# How to configure a password for LightDM VNC connection

Tags: lightdm, remote-desktop, vnc

I have ubuntu 14.04, and am using lightdm.
I want to login to the machine from another (windows) computer using VNC. By using the following /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf I get a VNC server, but when I try to connect to it I get (using chrome realVNC or TightVNC client) an error 'Authentication reason: No password configured for VNC auth'

> [SeatDefaults]
>   autologin-user=
>   user-seesion=ubuntu
>   greeter-session=unity-greeter
>   allow-guest=false
>   [XDMCPServer]
>   enabled=true
>   port=177
>   [VNCServer]
>   enabled=true
>   port=5900
>   width=1360
>   height=768
>   depth=24

I have used vncpasswd on the machine to set a password. However this is a password for a specific user (I think). Also 'update-alternatives --list Xvnc' points to:

- /usr/bin/Xvnc
- /usr/bin/Xvnc4

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late, but here is how to configure a password for lightdm integrated vnc :

```
# vncpasswd /etc/vncpasswd

# tail /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
command=/usr/bin/Xvnc -rfbauth /etc/vncpasswd
port=5900
width=1280
height=1024
depth=24
```

and restart lightdm